# Can I place php includes in a jquery accordion menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First off, still learning as I go so js is fairly new to me and this is my first attempt at jquery so if this seems basic, sorry.

It was suggested that the solution to my sidebar menu would be better is js or jquery and following the advice I have pieced together the below jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/q4Zyv/4/

Overall it's working the want but I'm trying to determine what to do next. The first menu (and submenus) are going to be a gallery and I want to show 12 tiled images. I can just drop the images into the li but I was thinking what would be nice to do would be to set up my images as a php include as I want to add more than just 12 per category later with an array or other method.

Based on this, can I add an include to the li? Does the jquery function and the way it calls heights prevent this. Any recommendations? I'm wanting to get this up as soon as possible even as a placeholder while I learn more and tweak later. Here is the code i the above fiddle:

```
body {
    background-color:#161616;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
#nestedAccordion {
    width:20%;
    min-width:200px;
    float:right;
    text-align:right;
}
#nestedAccordion h2, #nestedAccordion h3, #nestedAccordion div, #nestedAccordion ul, #nestedAccordion li {
    /* reset styles for accordion */
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:strong;
    list-style:circle;
    font-family:arial;
}
#nestedAccordion div {
    display:none;
    color:#121212;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#nestedAccordion h2 {
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:14px;
    padding:5px;
    margin:0px;
    background-color: #2d2d2d;
    border-top: #161616 1px solid;
}
#nestedAccordion h2:hover {
    background-color:#c569f2;
}
#nestedAccordion h3 {
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:5px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #3d3d3d;
}
#nestedAccordion h3:hover {
    background-color:#c569f2;
}
#nestedAccordion h3 + div {
    background-color:#4d4d4d;
    color:#ffffff;
    padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
#nestedAccordion ul {
    padding:0px;
    margin:-5px;
}
#nestedAccordion li {
    color:#ffffff;
}
#nestedAccordion li div {
    width:100%;
    min-width:200px;
    height:400px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
#nestedAccordion li:hover {
    background-color:#c569f2;
    cursor:pointer;
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    var parentDivs = $('#nestedAccordion div'),
        childDivs = $('#nestedAccordion h3').siblings('div');

    $('#nestedAccordion h2').click(function () {
        parentDivs.slideUp();
        if ($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
            $(this).next().slideDown();
        } else {
            $(this).next().slideUp();
        }
    });
    $('#nestedAccordion h3').click(function () {
        childDivs.slideUp();
        if ($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
            $(this).next().slideDown();
        } else {
            $(this).next().slideUp();
        }
    });
});


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nestedAccordion">

<h2>Portfolio</h2>

    <div>
            <h3>Branding</h3>

        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>Div/PHP goes here... calling 12 thumbnails</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
            <h3>Publications</h3>

        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>Div/PHP goes here</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
            <h3>Online</h3>

        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>Div/PHP goes here</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
            <h3>Advertisments</h3>

        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>Div/PHP goes here</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
<h3>Displays</h3>

        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>Div/PHP goes here</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

<h3>Packaging</h3>

        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>Div/PHP goes here</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

<h2>Blog</h2>

    <div>
            <ul style="margin:0px;">
                <li>entry 1</li>
                <li>entry 2</li>
            </ul>

    </div>
<h2>About</h2>

    <div>
 <!--           <h3>Production Central</h3>

        <div>-->
            <ul style="margin:0px;">
                <li>About</li>
                <li>Resume</li>
                <li>Accolades</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can embed php. Simply rename your .html to .php and start with `<?php` and close with `?>` inside the `<li>` tag where you want to include your php script

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can include php but don't forget that you need to wrap it in php tags like so:

```
<?php

// php code goes here
echo "content";

?>
```